# postgresql select duplicate records in codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

the method is returning duplicate records in postgress in mysql without problems but how do I solve it in postgress`enter code here`

public function getAllAdverts(bool $onlyDeleted = false)
{

```
    $builder = $this;

    if ($onlyDeleted) {

        $builder->onlyDeleted();
    }


    $tableFields = [
        'adverts.*',
        'categories.name AS category',
        'adverts_images.image AS images', 
    ];

    **$builder->select($tableFields);
    $builder->select('count(adverts_images.id)');
    $builder->join('categories', 'categories.id = adverts.category_id');
```

1. List item

   ```
   $builder->join('adverts_images', 'adverts_images.advert_id = adverts.id', 'LEFT');
   **$builder->groupBy('adverts.id,categories.name,adverts_images.image');** 
   $builder->orderBy('adverts.id', 'DESC');
   return $builder->findAll();**
   ```

   }